# Freeze after File No Longer Available Message

Tags: options

When I go to a buffer where the file was deleted Vim shows:

> E211: File "foo" no longer available

Vim freezes for about a second before it resumes. Where can I change/disable this delay or handle it in another way?

Comment: it looks like this is hard coded in the source.

Comment: That's too bad but thank you for looking into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @ChristianBrabandt, it looks like this is [hard coded](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/fileio.c#L4191,L4192) in the source:

```
                // give the user some time to think about it
                ui_delay(1004L, TRUE);
```